# .jar file extracted from Artifact build in Intellij won't open

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to extract .jar of my project through the artifact build in intellij but the extracted jar file is not opening. I'm using the jcommon .jar file which is external library and I also added this jar file to my project build.

[image]

[image]

Java is not a problem. I tried another project without any external libraries and it works well.

I also tried to edit the manifest file and add the classpath for the external libraries but same.

How to extract jar file with external libraries or jar file?

The error message is showing
Java application launch failed. Check Console for possible error messages related to 'Users/jaehunshim Desktop/CS/CS_IA/out/artifacts/ CS_IA_ iar2/Cs_IA jar'

Comment: Could you please translate the error message into English.

Comment: Java application launch failed.
Check Console for possible error messages related to  'Users/jaehunshim
Desktop/CS/CS_IA/out/artifacts/
CS_IA_ iar2/Cs_IA jar'

Comment: What error message do you see after running this jar in the OS terminal?